# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar una busqueda en SAP Service Layer?

Tags: sap

Estoy tratando de realizar un filtro en la búsqueda de clientes en SAP Service Layer pero al momento de ejecutar el endpoint no me da ningún resultado, intenté con éstos 2 ejemplos que encontré pero no me funcionan:

```
https://localhost:50000/b1s/v1/Quotations?$select=DocEntry,DocNum,DocType&$filter=DocEntry eq 1 &$orderby=DocEntry&$top=10&$skip=1

https://localhost:50000/b1s/v1/Quotations?$filter=DocNum eq 1
```

Habra alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

La petición que estas realizando es correcta. ¿Estas seguro que ya realizaste la conexión al Service Layer?

por ejemplo en mi entorno de pruebas al ejecutar

primero https://localhost:50000/b1s/v1/Login para conexión y luego.

https://localhost:50000/b1s/v1/Quotations?$filter=DocNum eq 36408

[image: Captura de pantalla en Postman]

Para mas información puedes documentarte en https://sap.highwaytwo.com/Service%20Layer%20API%20Reference.html